# Hook into order note creation from the admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to log some thing out. I've did a lot by myself but there is one topic left - the order note creation within an order from the admin dashboard:

[image]

I've found this hook here but no clue if this is the right one:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'test');
function test() {
    error_log('Trigger');
}
```

I need this to log only created notification from the dashboard by any user which has the permission for this.

Do you know any way to do this? The WooCommerce Documentation looks very bad about this topic.

Comment: That hook is located on checkout shipping form, so nothing related to admin order displayed notes…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Hmm this is the only hook I've found about notes :| Maybe there is no way to do this?

Comment: I don't see any available hook for that…

Comment: So there is no way to do this. Maybe I can hook into the mail sent to the customer? Mayyyyybeeeee :D